# Getting the largest value in sorted rdd using scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the logs like:

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
...
ERROR: SVN Problem
..
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
```

I wrote the below function to sort the errors, based on number of occurence of errors:

```
val getErrorLines=lines.filter(value=>value.startsWith("ERROR"))
val mappedErrors=getErrorLines.map((s => {
val substrings = s.split(":")
(substrings(1), substrings(0))
})).map(value=>(value,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).sortBy(_._2, false, 1)
```

I am able to get the sorted list of errors based on the number of occurrence of the error:

```
(( Error fetching remote repo 'origin',ERROR),5)
(( SVN Problem,ERROR),1)
```

But i want only the highest occurring error which is :

```
(( Error fetching remote repo 'origin',ERROR),5)
```

I piped the top() function on the sort , but it still gave me :

```
(( SVN Problem,ERROR),1)
```

Is there any other function which would give me the largest occurance based on the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `first`:

```
val mostFrequentError = 
s.split(":")(substrings(1), substrings(0))}))
.map(value=>(value,1))
.reduceByKey(_+_)
.sortBy(_._2, false, 1)
.first()
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solutions is to `swap`

```
val substrings = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (("Error fetching remote repo 'origin'", "ERROR"), 5),
  (("SVN Problem", "ERROR"), 1)
))

substrings.map(_.swap).top(1)
// Array[(Int, (String, String))] = Array((5,(Error fetching remote repo 'origin',ERROR)))
```

Comment: If there are more than 2 error types, then the swap would not help, since it gives indifferent output.
But a nice util to have.Thanks !!

Comment: @KeshavPradeepRamanath swap is a method of `Tuple2` and swaps the elements such that the count is on first position, top will then order by count

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `max` method on `RDD`

If the default result is not ok for your use-case, you can send an ordering function. I think that in your case, since the highest is the one with the highest integer in the second part of the tuple this will work fine:

```
rdd.max()(Ordering[Int].on(x=>x._2))
```

Quick test here:

[image]

Comment: Yup..this one works .In this case we will need the ordering function associated with the values that are worked upon.Is that right?

Comment: Actually you dont need to order your rdd at all. The Max function work the same regardless the rdd being ordered or not